# How to map my Windows C drive in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu

I need to map my Windows `C:\` drive in Ubuntu.  How could I accomplish this?

Comment: Perhaps better asked on http://ubuntu.stackexchange.com

Comment: Not enough info. Is your C: on the same computer as Ubuntu (dual-boot) or is it a different computer on a network?

Answer (score 4):

Right click your C drive then go to Properties > Sharing > Advanced Sharing and tick "Share this folder"

On your Ubuntu pc:

```
$ sudo apt-get install smbfs
$ sudo mkdir /mnt/c
$ sudo mount -t smbfs //192.168.0.2/c /mntc -o username=<yourusername>,password=<yourpassword>
```

(assuming that your windows machine has IP address 192.168.0.2 and you have chosen "c" as your share name)

Answer (score 2):

Try this [link](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/mountwindows).

It tells you how to install ntfs-config.  Once you have that software, you can permanently mount your Windows partition.

Comment: This assumes that your Windows drive is on the same computer.  If you want a network share, follow Russell's suggestion.